# Excel VBA: can I set up a global right click event?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create an event so that a certain .xlam of mine gets control whenever the user right-clicks ?   In this case the user may have several .xlsx (non-macro) workbooks open which must remain free of any macro code.  If the user right-clicks while one of these macro-free worksheets is open, I'd like the .xlam to gain control and possibly do something.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a with events variable in a class such as

```
Private WithEvents mxlApp As Excel.Application
```

Then use the event SheetBeforeRightClick.

```
Private Sub mxlApp_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

The xlsx files should have the .xlam file installed in order for it to work. Hope this helps.

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick.  In this case I just put the "WithEvents" variable in the Workbook (module level variable), initialized by the workbook open method.  No need to define an additional class - works great - thanks again.